# Mysql Match() Against() does not work

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, match-against

I am using `MATCH.....AGAINST` in `phpMyAdmin` but it does not work
Here is table.

```
id     sentence
1      get software free
2      here software download
```

Here is a query for `phpMyAdmin`

```
SELECT * FROM `phrase` WHERE MATCH(sentence) AGAINST('software' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

It returns no result.Why?
But a word **software** is present in both sentence.
Please guide me about this.
Thanks....

Answer (score 1):

Is your table **MYISAM**? I've done a test here and it works fine.

```
CREATE TABLE `foo` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `sentence` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


insert into foo values (null, 'get software free');
insert into foo values (null, 'here software download');

mysql> SELECT * FROM `foo` WHERE MATCH(sentence) AGAINST('software' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
+----+------------------------+
| id | sentence               |
+----+------------------------+
|  1 | get software free      |
|  2 | here software download |
+----+------------------------+
```

Comment: Add one more row `INSERT INTO foo (id, sentence) VALUES (NULL, 'search softwarename');` Now query change with that `SELECT * FROM foo WHERE MATCH(sentence) AGAINST('software*' IN BOOLEAN MODE);`  
Now it select this row **3    search softwarename**.This query work well but other one not.

Comment: Yes my table is **MYISAM**

Comment: How about the field sentence.. Is it varchar, text. Could you give us your show create table ? cheers